# How To Filter Determined Result Queries That Appear More Than Once in Ms.Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

Let's say i've 2 following tables, the 2nd is `datetime` format from fingerprint scanner :

1.[time_setup table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEYfq.png)

2.[checktime table, `tapping_time` field is data from fingerprint scanner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKxrR.png)

then i want to get result **without** more than one tapping on a time setup like 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGPMk.png)
because some people do the tap more than once at a time

how to create SELECT in Ms.Access SQL ?

Answer (score 1):

It could be:

```
Select 
    UserId,
    DateValue(tapping_time) As [Date],
    Min(TimeValue(tapping_time)) As Tapping_on,
    IIf(Hour(tapping_time) \ 12, "Evening", "Morning") As Session
From
    CheckTime
Group By
    UserId,
    DateValue(tapping_time),
    Hour(tapping_time) \ 12
```

Notice the integer division with "\".

Comment: It's work, but only give me two conditions of time, how if i've 5 time (not only morning & evening) conditions with determined hour and minutes included ?

Comment: Well, we can only try to answer what you ask for, and that was _morning_ and _evening_.

Comment: i've asked more specified question in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49122943/filter-result-between-time-range-and-get-only-one-on-it-ms-access